# How to merge cells (colspan) using jsf h:panelGrid?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Suppose I want display table:

```
+--------------------------------+
|        |           |           |
----------------------------------
|                    |           |
----------------------------------
|        |                       |
----------------------------------
|        |           |           |
----------------------------------
|        |           |           |
+--------------------------------+
```

How can I do that with `h:panelGrid`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this with the standard JSF implementation. In JSF 1.2 one would have used [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/index.html) [`<t:panelGroup colspan="2">`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tlddoc/t/panelGroup.html) for this. Right now Tomahawk is not officially compatible with JSF 2.0, but I just gave it a try.

```
<html xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
...
<t:panelGrid columns="3">
    <t:panelGroup>row1cell1</t:panelGroup>
    <t:panelGroup>row1cell2</t:panelGroup>
    <t:panelGroup>row1cell3</t:panelGroup>

    <t:panelGroup colspan="2">row2cell1-2</t:panelGroup>
    <t:panelGroup>row2cell3</t:panelGroup>

    <t:panelGroup>row3cell1</t:panelGroup>
    <t:panelGroup colspan="2">row3cell2-3</t:panelGroup>

    <t:panelGroup>row4cell1</t:panelGroup>
    <t:panelGroup>row4cell2</t:panelGroup>
    <t:panelGroup>row4cell3</t:panelGroup>
</t:panelGrid>
```

And it works. I don't guarantee that other Tomahawk components will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think core JSF supports this, but some 3rd-party implementations might.  Someone posted a solution to this using Tomahawk at the end of the post at the following URL:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/211242/JSF/java/colspan